# What is the difference between Informatica parameters?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

What is the difference between $myvar and $$myvar parameters in Informatica PowerCenter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually **$** means internal Parameter/Variable (such as $DBConnection prefix or $PMSessionLogDir) whereas **$$** are used for user-defined parameters or variables (which could be defined at mapping or workflow/worklet level).

You can declare and use variables and parameters starting with **$$**
You can override and use pre-defined parameters starting with **$PM*** (i.e. $PMSessionLogDir, $PMWorkflowLogCount)
You can use without declaration parameters following predefined templates (i.e. $InputFile, $DBConnection, etc.).

I hope this all make more sense to you.

Regards,

--
YM

Answer (score 1):

**$** means Session Parameter/Session Variable

**$$** means Mapping Parameter/Mapping Variable

Comment: Ok, is there also Workflow parameters / variables?

Comment: @jrara im new to informatica and i have came across only three parameters...third ive read was '$$$' system parameter/variable.So i guess there are no workflow parameters